# glfwDestroyWindow won't close window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have a program with OpenGL running in a secondary thread. If the render loop is done, I call glfwDestroyWindow(). However, the window won't close before I exit the main thead. If I try to close it several times (by repeatedly clicking on the x), a window pops up that says the window is not responding and asks me to force quit.

Why does [glfwDestroyWindow](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#gacdf43e51376051d2c091662e9fe3d7b2) not properly close my window?

EDIT: By the way, I am using GLFW3.

EDIT2:

This is how my code looks like, basically. I can see the output while the window is still open. The window is only closed when I either force close it or exit the main thread.

Main thread:

```
int main() {
    startOpenGLThread();
    while(1);
}
```

OpenGL thread:

```
Window::start() {
    initGLFW();
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose());
    glfwDestroyWindow();
    cout << "I can see this ouput, but the window is still open!" << endl;
}
```

EDIT3:

The window closes if I put the glfwTerminate() right behind the output, obviously. However, this is not what I want, because I may have other windows opened.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `glfwPollEvents()` or `glfwWaitEvents()` for the close button event to be processed. Insert one `glfwWaitEvents();` into your loop and the window should close properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling glfwDestroyWindow() from inside the main loop.  A basic GLFW application should look something like this

```
GLFWwindow * win = glfwCreateWindow(...)

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(win)) {
  ... process input ...
  glfwMakeContextCurrnet(win);
  ... do rendering stuff ...
  glfwSwapBuffers(win);
}
glfwDestroyWindow(win);
```

In order to close the application, presumably there's some bit of input that you'll interpret as a shutdown command.  If a person hits 'ESC' you can pick that up in a GLFW key callback handler.  But when you get that signal you should NOT call `glfwDestroyWindow()`.  Instead you should call `glfwSetWindowShouldClose(win, 1)` to tell GLFW that it can exit the primary loop and destroy the window safely in the main thread.

Comment: I already do it like you said. However, glfwCreateWindow, the loop, and glfwDestroyWindow are all in the secondary thread.

Comment: Quick question: Why do you call glfwMakeContextCurrent inside the loop? Isn't it sufficient once before the loop?

Comment: If you're only working with a single window in your application, yes, it's sufficient to call `glfwMakeContextCurrent` once after creating the window.

Comment: If you're already doing this, then you should provide a small bit of sample code on what the main thread looks like and what the secondary thread looks like.  You probably have a simple race condition.

Comment: I provided a basic outline of my code in my question now. I don't see a race condition.

Comment: A `while(1);` loop will never exit, regardless of what happens to the window.  Is that really what you're doing or is there interaction with some other windowing system or 'exit flag' variable there?

Comment: I just commented all the code out that was inside the while(1) loop and the proplem is still there. So, no, it does not interact with the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to close the window first in this way:

```
glfwSetWindowShouldClose(win, true);
glfwDestroyWindow(win);
```